# при выборе chekbox меняются поля ввода

Tags: php, jquery

Проблема такого рода
при выборе одного из чекбоксов у меня выводятся или прячуться некоторые поля в форме.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
var ajax_timeout=false,
delay_beforesend=300;
function sendForm(){$.ajax(
{
```

Здесь данные отправляются обработчику на php

```
url:'calc-function2.php',
data:$('form').serialize(),
dataType: "json",
method:'post',
success: function(response)
{
    $("#vesburovoi").html(response.vesburovoi);
    $("#lstolb").html(response.lstolb);
    $("#shebenka").html(response.shebenka);
    $("#vproftruba").html(response.vproftruba);
    $("#vesproftrubi").html(response.vesproftrubi);
    $("#vesprofnastila").html(response.vesprofnastila);
    $("#amount").html(response.amount);
    $("#stvork").html(response.stvork);
}})}

$('form').find('select, input').change(function()
{
if(ajax_timeout) clearTimeout(ajax_timeout);
ajax_timeout=setTimeout(sendForm,delay_beforesend)
})})
```

Злесь скрываем открываем одну из таблиц или блоков

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#mode_1').hide();
$('#mode_2').hide();
$('#mode_3').hide();
$('input:radio[name=mode]').change(function(){
var ddd = $(this).val();

    if (ddd == 'zabor_vorota')
    {
        $('#mode_1').show();
        $('#mode_2').hide();
        $('#mode_3').hide();
    }

    if(ddd == 'zabor')
    {
        $('#mode_1').hide();
        $('#mode_2').show();
        $('#mode_3').hide();

    }

    if(ddd == 'vorota')
    {
        $('#mode_1').hide();
        $('#mode_2').hide();
        $('#mode_3').show();

    }
});
});/*end  ready*/
</script>
```

html

```
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>Забор + ворота:</td>'."\n";
echo '<td>
<input type="radio" name="mode" value="zabor_vorota" style="vertical-align:middle;" /> 
<span style="vertical-align:middle;"></span>';
echo '</td>'."\n";
echo '</tr>';

echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>Только Забор:</td>'."\n";
echo '<td>
<input type="radio" name="mode" value="zabor" style="vertical-align:middle;" /> 
<span style="vertical-align:middle;"></span>';
echo '</td>'."\n";
echo '</tr>';

echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>Только Ворота:</td>'."\n";
echo '<td>
<input type="radio" name="mode" value="vorota" style="vertical-align:middle;" /> 
<span style="vertical-align:middle;"></span>';
echo '</td>'."\n";
echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';
```

Вот тут выводится одна из трех таблиц, но проблема в том, что даже если остальные скрыты, то данные из них все равно отправляются, да и имена у некоторых одинаковые (чтобы не создавать кучу переменных).
Как сделать чтобы данные из скрытых полей не отправлялись?
Или же отправлялись, но разным обработчикам, не всем сразу, а конкретно одному из трех, если такие будут :)

```
echo '<table id="mode_1"><input name="name"><input name="name2"></table>';
echo '<table id="mode_2"><input name="name"><input name="name2"></table>';
echo '<table id="mode_3"><input name="name"><input name="name2"></table>';
```

Comment: Вы вполне можете использовать вместо `$('form').serialize()` произвольную логику выборки данных для отправки на сервер. Достаточно просто отфильтровывать значения скрытых полей.

Comment: Все бы ничего, но я только постигаю это все

Comment: Живой бы пример

Comment: Того, как выбирать произвольные данные для отправки на сервер? Пожалуйста: http://jsfiddle.net/3zs5mygj/

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить в конце функции change чекбокса проверку на видимость таблицы и добавлять невидимым полям атрибут disabled. Такие поля не будут обрабатываться serialize. Примерно так:

```
 $('table input:not(:visible)').prop('disabled', true);
```