# объеденить две функции jquery

Tags: jquery

Я только учусь, поэтому сильно не ругайтесь..
Есть две функции, одна отправляет, получает данные,
вторая скрывает, показывает блоки, в каждом из которых форма,
при скрытии и открытии блока должна создаваться или удаляться переменная с id формы и передаваться в функцию  которая собирает с этой формы данные и отправляет. Да, и в идеале бы отправлять только те переменные, которые не пустые...

```
<script type="text/javascript">


$(function(){
var ajax_timeout=false,
delay_beforesend=300;
var tableid;
$('#mode_1').hide();
$('#mode_2').hide();
$('#mode_3').hide();


$('input:radio[name=mode]').change(function(){

  var ddd = $(this).val();

    if (ddd == 'zabor_vorota')
    {
        $('#mode_1').show();
        $('#mode_2').hide();
        $('#mode_3').hide();
        tableid = 'mode_1';

        }



   if(ddd == 'zabor')
    {
        $('#mode_1').hide();
        $('#mode_2').show();
        $('#mode_3').hide();
        tableid = 'mode_2';


    }

 if (ddd == 'vorota')
    {
        $('#mode_1').hide();
        $('#mode_2').hide();
        $('#mode_3').show();
        tableid = 'mode_3';


        }



    })

function sendForm(){$.ajax(
{

url:'calc-function2.php',
data:$('#cmode_1').serialize(),
dataType: "json",
method:'post',

success: function(response)
{

    $("#vesburovoi").html(response.vesburovoi);
    $("#lstolb").html(response.lstolb);
    $("#shebenka").html(response.shebenka);
    $("#vproftruba").html(response.vproftruba);
    $("#vesproftrubi").html(response.vesproftrubi);
    $("#vesprofnastila").html(response.vesprofnastila);
    $("#amount").html(response.amount);
    $("#stvork").html(response.stvork);
    $("#zabor").html(response.zabor);
    $("#metrzabora").html(response.metrzabora);
    $("#ves").html(response.ves);
    $("#dostavka").html(response.dostavka);
    $("#ves_dresvi").html(response.ves_dresvi);
    $("#ves_cementa").html(response.ves_cementa);
    $("#vorota").html(response.vorota);
    $("#kalitka").html(response.kalitka);
    $("#avto").html(response.avto);
    $("#generator").html(response.generator);
    $("#kolvostolb").html(response.kolvostolb);
    $("#lproftrubi").html(response.lproftrubi);
    $("#kolvoprf").html(response.kolvoprf);
    $("#meshkcem").html(response.meshkcem);
    $("#meshkdresvi").html(response.meshkdresvi);
    $("#samorez").html(response.samorez);
    $("#lprof40x40").html(response.lprof40x40);
    $("#zamok").html(response.zamok);
    $("#summa").html(response.summa);
    $("#pokraska").html(response.pokraska);
    $("#stolb_pod_vorota").html(response.stolb_pod_vorota);
    $("#hzabor").html(response.hzabor);
    $("#lzabor").html(response.lzabor);
    $("#proklep").html(response.proklep);
    $("#profnastil").html(response.profnastil);
    $("#demontazh").html(response.demontazh);
    $("#klepki").html(response.klepki);
    $("#mezhdustlb").html(response.mezhdustlb);
    $("#vrta").html(response.vrta);
    $("#kltk").html(response.kltk);
    $("#vrmke").html(response.vrmke);
    $("#zmk").html(response.zmk);
    $("#pokrkarkasa").html(response.pokrkarkasa);
    $("#dm").html(response.dm);
    $("#bnzg").html(response.bnzg);
    $("#otposta").html(response.otposta);
    $("#ves_stolbov_vk").html(response.ves_stolbov_vk);
    $("#pr").html(response.pr);
    $("#zarplata").html(response.zarplata);
    $("#dostav").html(response.dostavka);
    $("#metr_sebest").html(response.metr_sebest);
    $("#stolb_vorot").html(response.stolb_vorot);
    $("#stkraska").html(response.stkraska);
}})}
$('form').find('select, input').change(function()
{
if(ajax_timeout) clearTimeout(ajax_timeout);
ajax_timeout=setTimeout(sendForm,delay_beforesend)
})})

</script>

<?php
echo '<form id="calc" action="">'."\n";

echo '<table class="result">'."\n";


echo '<tr>'."\n";
echo '<th class="raschet-title" colspan="2">Что нужно рассчитать</th>'."\n";
echo '</tr>'."\n";


echo '<tr>'."\n";
echo '<td>Забор + ворота:</td>'."\n";
echo '<td>'."\n";
echo '<input type="radio" name="mode" value="zabor_vorota" style="vertical-align:middle;" />'."\n"; 
echo '<span style="vertical-align:middle;"></span>'."\n";
echo '</td>'."\n";
echo '</tr>'."\n";

echo '<tr>'."\n";
echo '<td>Только Забор:</td>'."\n";
echo '<td>'."\n";
echo '<input type="radio" name="mode" value="zabor" style="vertical-align:middle;" /> '."\n";
echo '<span style="vertical-align:middle;"></span>'."\n";
echo '</td>'."\n";
echo '</tr>'."\n";

echo '<tr>'."\n";
echo '<td>Только Ворота:</td>'."\n";
echo '<td>'."\n";
echo '<input type="radio" name="mode" value="vorota" style="vertical-align:middle;" />'."\n";
echo '<span style="vertical-align:middle;"></span>'."\n";
echo '</td>'."\n";
echo '</tr>'."\n";

echo '</table>'."\n";

echo '<table class="result" id = "mode_1">';
...
echo '</table>';


echo '<table class="result" id = "mode_2">';
...
echo '</table>';


echo '<table class="result" id = "mode_3">';
...
echo '</table>';
echo '</form>';
?>
```

Если напрямую прописать в отправку идентификатор формы #calc, то данные отправляются, а если идентификатор таблицы mode_1 или 2 или 3, то данные не уходят

```
 <form id = "calc">
<table id="mode_1"></table>
<table id="mode_2"></table>
<table id="mode_3"></table>
</form>
```

Comment: Мне кажется или это повторение вопроса http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/443150/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5-chekbox-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объявите переменную formid сразу после

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
var formid;
```

А тут уберите var:

```
var formid= 'calc1';
```

Тогда область видимости переменной formid позволит использовать ее в обеих функциях.
В функции отправки пропишите так:

```
data:$('#'+formid).serialize()
```

Comment: Что то я тут нагородил, сейчас данные не отпраавляются :(

Comment: Покажите ваш код

Comment: Извиняюсь, проверил, методом alert, значения действительно подставляются в data:$('#'+formid).serialize(), проблема сейчас в другом

Comment: Внизу добавил пояснение

Comment: Вы хотите отправлять только данные только видимых таблиц, верно?

Comment: Да, верно......

Comment: Я ответил на другой ваш вопрос, как это можно сделать.

Comment: Но появляется проблема, что отправляются либо данные id calc , либо ничего

Comment: Собственно можно думаю создать отдельные формы для каждой таблицы отдельно, раз уж данные беруться только если подставлять id формы

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27016/discussion-between-plikard-and-dikkiy).